# Session Fixation - Setting path to root without /

Tags: xss, session-fixation

I have found an XSS vulnerability on the subdomain of a site I am testing, and using it I can set cookies for both the main site and all it's subdomains.

My url currently looks like this:

```
http://s1.example.com/u/%22%3E%3Cmeta%20http-equiv=Set-Cookie%20content=%22sid=1234;%20path=/;%20expires=Thursday,%2020-May-15%2000:15:00%20GMT;%20domain=example.com%22%3E
```

The issue is that for some reason or another, the character "/" is filtered out (no other characters are), meaning that although I can set cookies to the main site and all it's subdomains, I can only set them to the path /u/ as that is where the attack is launched from on the subdomain. Is there any way to set the path to / without actually using the `/`?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your content is going into an HTML attribute, encoded in a URL. That gives you two possible forms of encoding:

- URL-encoding: `%2F`. Although this should in principle work, both IIS and Apache block the use of URL-encoded slashes due to some past security issues.
- HTML-encoding: `&#47;`, or rather as it is itself in a URL, `%26%2347%3B`.

(Although... since you appear to have an injection into HTML attribute, is there any reason not to go straight for the more-damaging and better-supported `%22%3E%3Cscript%3E...`?)

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding the / character with the hex representation `%2F`.

Comment: Tried that but annoyingly it doesn't work either. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whole `%20path=/` section - the HTTP response header should set everything at root level.

If that doesn't work inside a `meta http-eqiv`, try the HTML encoded version of the path as because the content is in HTML should be correctly decoded (`&#47;`).

Alternatively you could inject JavaScript to set the cookie via client-side script and set the path via entity encoding (`\x2f`).

Comment: Annoyingly the HTTP response header won't set it at root level, only at /u/. I also tried HTML encoding but sadly it did not work.

Comment: @WH567 Updated answer

Comment: Once again no luck. Seems like this may not be quite as vulnerable as originally thought (although it definitely has a huge number of problems).